# Does a Galois extension always have the same order over the field from which it is extended for which polynomial it is a splitting field for?

Tags: galois-theory

Does a Galois extension always have the same order over the field from which it is extended for which polynomial it is a splitting field for?

My example is the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)/\mathbb{Q}$

[let $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)$]

Using the tower law and basic field extensions I was able to find that $[L:\mathbb{Q}] = 8$

However I know that L is the splitting field for the degree 6 polynomial $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-5)$

I know it is Galois since $[L:\mathbb{Q}] = \text{Card}(\text{Aut}(L/\mathbb{Q}))= 8$, and also because it is the splitting field for a separable polynomial

I am stuck here, how is $[L:\mathbb{Q}]$ 8 but L the splitting field for a polynomial of degree 6 contained in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, where am I fundamentally misunderstanding Galois theory?

P.S. I am doing an undergraduate course in Galois theory so my knowledge on the subject is evidently undeveloped.

Comment: I'm finding the title a little hard to parse

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but maybe this is relevant:  Consider $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb Q$.  The splitting field for that has degree $6$ over the rationals (easy exercise).

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polynomial $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-5)$ is clearly reducible over $\Bbb Q$, so it is not a minimal polynomial of (any of) the roots. We can't then claim $[L:\Bbb Q]=\text{degree of polynomial}$ despite the fact that $L$ is the splitting field for this polynomial. Indeed, all roots have degree $2$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Another place a confusion like this can arise: the Galois group acts transitively on the roots of irreducible polynomials,  but not necessarily over reducible ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer has helped me a lot, sorry for the confusing title :)

Comment: @MaxwellHolmes You’re welcome :)